# How to read doc file for the first four paragraph using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Reading the doc file and extract the content, able to read the entire doc file, but how can I read the first four paragraphs in the doc file?

code:

```
HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fis);
WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);
String[] paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();
System.out.println("Total no of paragraph in the file "+paragraphs.length);                                                   
for (String para : paragraphs) {
    System.out.println(para);
}
fis.close();
```

from the above its contains 25 paragraph, so how can I read first 4 paragraphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Result

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
if(paragraphs[i] != null)
System.out.println(paragraphs[i]);    
}
```